# Using SendMailMapi() in C++Builder 10.4.1 with and without the Windows 10 SDK installed

Tags: c++, c++builder, mapi

I have 2 computers, both with C++Builder 10.4.1 installed, only 1 has Windows 10 SDK.

When I compile and run my program with the following code, `SendMailMapi()` throws an Access Violation.

On systems without the SDK, the code compiles and runs just fine. Any ideas what the problem is?

```
#include <Winapi.Mapi.hpp>
#include <mapi.h>

...
lots of stuff here
...
SendMailMapi("email address", "mail subject", "Text", FileName(attachment));

...

bool __fastcall Tmyform::SendMailMapi(AnsiString ToAddr, AnsiString Subj, AnsiString Msg, AnsiString AttFile)
{
  //
  AnsiString fp, fn;
  int dwResult;

  fn = Application->ExeName;
  if (fn.Pos(".\\")) {
    fn = fn.Delete(fn.Pos(".\\"), 2);
  }
  fn = ExtractFilePath(fn);
  fp = ExtractFilePath(AttFile);
  if (fp.Pos(".\\")) {
    fp = fp.Delete(fp.Pos(".\\"), 2);
  }
  fn = fn + fp + ExtractFileName(AttFile);
  HINSTANCE hMAPI;
  LPMAPISENDMAIL pSendMail;
  TMapiMessage *message = new TMapiMessage;
   message->flFlags = 0;
  TMapiFileTagExt *filetag = new TMapiFileTagExt;
  //dwResult = message->flFlags;
  filetag->ulReserved = 0;
  filetag->cbEncoding = 0;
  filetag->cbTag = 0;
  filetag->lpTag = NULL;
  filetag->lpEncoding = NULL;
  TMapiFileDesc *file = new TMapiFileDesc;
  file->ulReserved = 0;
  file->flFlags = 0;
  file->nPosition = -1;
  file->lpszPathName = fn.c_str();
  file->lpszFileName = fn.c_str();
  file->lpFileType = filetag;
  TMapiRecipDesc *Recpt = new TMapiRecipDesc;
  Recpt->ulReserved = 0;
  Recpt->ulRecipClass = MAPI_TO;
  Recpt->lpszName = ""; // (wchar_t *)
  Recpt->lpszAddress = ToAddr.c_str(); //  (wchar_t *)
  Recpt->ulEIDSize = 0;
  Recpt->lpEntryID = NULL;

  hMAPI = LoadLibraryA( "MAPI32.DLL" );

  pSendMail = (LPMAPISENDMAIL)GetProcAddress( hMAPI, "MAPISendMail" );

  message->lpszSubject     = Subj.c_str(); // (wchar_t *)
  message->lpszNoteText    = Msg.c_str(); //  (wchar_t *)
  message->lpszMessageType = "";  //  (wchar_t *)
  message->nRecipCount     = 1;
  message->lpRecips        = Recpt;
  message->nFileCount      = 1;
  message->lpFiles         = file;
  message->lpOriginator    = NULL;
  //dwResult = message->flFlags;

  dwResult = pSendMail( lhSessionNull, (DWORD)0, message, MAPI_LOGON_UI | MAPI_DIALOG, 0 );
  if( dwResult == SUCCESS_SUCCESS )
  {
    // ...yay! :)
  }
  else
  {
    // ...we always fail here with: MAPI_E_FAILURE
  }
 }
```

Found it, sorry for delay
some more detail to make this thing happy!

Comment: have you tried using the debugger to find out what causes the access violation?

Comment: Access Violation is in mapi32.dll

Comment: call Stack I get is as follows::6c2640bc ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MAPI32.DLL
:6c263edf ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MAPI32.DLL
:6c2623df ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MAPI32.DLL
:6c26274b ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MAPI32.DLL
:0041F586 TEditEntries::SendMailMapi(this=:032EB530, ToAddr={ "email@gmail.com" }, Subj={ " 7/17/2021" }, Msg={ "message" }, AttFile={ "file.pdf" })

Comment: `TEditEntries::SendMailMapi()` is not a native C++Builder class function.  What does the code inside of `SendMailMapi()` look like?

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine. Code completion will give framework for sendmailmapi.

Comment: So, `TEditEntries::SendMailMapi()` is 3rd party code, not something you wrote? It certainly is not something built in to C++Builder, so you had to have gotten it from somewhere. `<Winapi.Mapi.hpp>` is just a wrapper for `<mapi.h>`, which itself is part of the MAPI SDK. There is no `SendMailMapi()` function in the SDK. But your call stack clearly shows a `TEditEntries` class with a `SendMailMapi()` class method.  So how is that class calling into the MAPI API? Is it using the Win32 `MAPISendMail()` function? We can't help you troubleshoot the Access Violation without a [mcve] showing more code.

Comment: update! seem to be a problem on just the one machine as complied working from other gives access violation on problem machine. Any new ideas?

Comment: Added code to listing. What a pain. BTW, the mapi.dlls on the 2 machines do not appear to be the same. Could be another windoze problem?

Comment: Working computer is running 20H2, nonworking is 21H1, suggestions?

Comment: @toml the code is not checking to make sure `LoadLibraryA()` and `GetProcAddress()` are successful. Is either one returning NULL on the failing machine, by chance?

Comment: have checked, both work fine, no null returns. and neither return the address in the error message.

Comment: one other thing I checked, on the 20h2(working) the win 10 sdk is Not installed. It is installed on the 21h1.  Have built code on both machines, both builds run on the 20h2, neither run on the 21h1. Compile with static links to ease use on machines which don't have the ide installed.